# Запуск Activity из другого модуля

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, sdk

Хочу запустить activity из другого модуля делаю так

```
 package="org.compliс.sign.auth.ui"

 <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="org.compliс.sign.auth.ui.AUTH_ACTION" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".CompliсMainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.compliс.sign.auth.ui.AUTH_ACTION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>
```

вызываю

```
private const val AUTH_ACTION = "org.compliс.sign.auth.ui.AUTH_ACTION"
private const val AUTH_PACKAGE = "org.compliс.sign.auth.ui"

internal fun start(context: Context){
    val intent = Intent( AUTH_ACTION, null).apply {
        setPackage(AUTH_PACKAGE)
    }
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Получаю ошибку

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=org.compliс.sign.auth.ui.AUTH_ACTION pkg=org.compliс.sign.auth.ui }
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте Class.forName

```
Intent intent = null;
    try {
        intent = new Intent(this, 
           Class.forName("org.compliс.sign.auth.ui.CompliсMainActivity"));
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```